# Send a figure through a pipe

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, multiprocessing

Im trying to make a gui where sensor data will be displayed on real time. My program has 4 processes and a main that gets everything going. 2 processes (lets call them sensor processes) just generate random numbers and send them through a pipe to a third process. This processes makes a matplotlib animation on a figure that then is sent to the last process who shows the figure on a tkinter gui. This is just a test to see if it is posible, the end game is to have a bunch of processes that make other animations using the data from the sensors and send them all to the gui where they can be shown when the user decides so in the gui. The problem i have is that when i execute the code the gui will show an empty figure with no animation. I dont know if this is the correct way to doit or if there is a better one all help is welcomed.
I will add the code bellow:

```
################### main ######################
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
from process_1 import Process_1
from process_2 import Process_2
from process_both import Figure_both
from process_GUI import Figure_distrib

if __name__ == "__main__":

    freeze_support()

    pipe_end_1, pipe_end_2 = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    pipe_end_3, pipe_end_4 = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    pipe_end_5, pipe_end_6 = multiprocessing.Pipe()


    p1 = Process_1(pipe1=pipe_end_1)
    p1.start()

    p2 = Process_2(pipe2=pipe_end_3)
    p2.start()

    fb = Figure_both(pipe1=pipe_end_2, pipe2=pipe_end_4, pipe3 = pipe_end_5)
    fb.start()

    gui = Figure_distrib(pipe3 = pipe_end_6)
    gui.start()

############### process_1 ##################

import multiprocessing
import random

class Process_1(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, pipe1=None):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.pipe1 = pipe1

    def run(self):
        while True:
            y1 = random.randint(0,50)
            self.pipe1.send(y1)

################### process_2 ###########################
import multiprocessing
import random
import time

class Process_2(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, pipe2=None):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.pipe2 = pipe2

    def run(self):
        while True:
            y2 = random.randint(0,50)
            self.pipe2.send(y2)


############## process_both ####################

import multiprocessing
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import tkinter as tk


both = plt.figure()
b1 = both.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
b2 = both.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)

class Figure_both(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, pipe1=None, pipe2=None, pipe3=None):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.pipe1 = pipe1
        self.pipe2 = pipe2
        self.pipe3 = pipe3

    def Get_data(self):
        if self.pipe1.poll():
            y1 = self.pipe1.recv()
        if self.pipe2.poll():
            y2 = self.pipe2.recv()

        values = (y1,y2)
        return y1,y2

    def animateboth(self,i):
        y1, y2 = self.Get_data()

        b1.clear()
        b1.bar(1, y1, width = 0.4)
        b1.hlines(xmin = 0, xmax = 2, y = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50], linestyles= '--', color = 'gray')

        b2.clear()
        b2.bar(1, y2, width = 0.4)
        b2.hlines(xmin = 0, xmax = 2, y = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50], linestyles= '--', color = 'gray')

### this code sends the figure
    def run(self):
        ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(both, self.animateboth, interval= 100)
        self.pipe3.send(both)

###

### This code shows the figure that should be sent
#     def run(self):
#         gui = GUI()
#
#         ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(both, self.animateboth, interval=100)
#
#         gui.mainloop()
#
#
# class GUI(tk.Tk):
#     def __init__(self):
#         tk.Tk.__init__(self)
#
#         canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(both,self)
#         canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
###


############################### process_GUI ################################

import multiprocessing
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import tkinter as tk
import threading



class Figure_distrib(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, pipe3=None):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.pipe3 = pipe3

    def update_fig(self):
        both = self.pipe3.recv()
        return both


    def run(self):
        both = self.update_fig()
        gui = GUI(both)
        gui.mainloop()


class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,both):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.both = both
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.both,self)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
```

Comment: Why are the processes that make and show the animation separate?

Comment: `Tk` objects cannot exist across multiple processes. You can have multiple processes all feeding data to a single process where tk displays that data from (which seems like what you're already doing in `Figure_both`)... The same goes for Qt, and probably most gui libraries.

Comment: Then how can I avoid the GUI being slowed by the animation? Because the thing is that i want to have multiple animations working at the same time but the GUI slows down horribly when I try.